# Not deleting file from Google Drive using Google Script + Google SpreadSheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script in my Google SpreadSheet that save my Google Sheet to a XLSX format on every edit i made. It is working fine, but its is creating a new file with the same name (many files with the same name, not overwriting, in the same folder).

I´d like to remove the old file and save the new version OR just overwrite the file that use the same name

My code is:

```
function getGoogleSpreadsheetAsExcel(){

  try {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + ss.getId() + "&exportFormat=xlsx";
    var params = {
      method      : "get",
      headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
      muteHttpExceptions: true
    };

    var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();
    blob.setName(ss.getName() + ".xlsx");

    // set the folder where I am working using the id
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(“FOLDER_ID");

    var xname = “blablabla.xlsx"; //set the file name
    var existing = folder.getFilesByName(xname);
    if (existing.hasNext()) {
      Browser.msgBox(‘file exists, delete to save the new version after.', Browser.Buttons.OK);

    // 'DELETE THE OLD FILE FROM GOOGLE DRIVE' CODE GOES HERE      


      Browser.msgBox(‘file deleted.', Browser.Buttons.OK);
      var arquivo = folder.createFile(blob); //save the new version
      Browser.msgBox(‘new version was saved.', Browser.Buttons.OK);
    }

    else {
      Browser.msgBox(‘file does not exists, saving.', Browser.Buttons.OK);
      var arquivo = folder.createFile(blob); //save the file
      Browser.msgBox(‘file saved.', Browser.Buttons.OK); //file saved
    }


  } catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f.toString());
  }
}
```

Help me to delete or overwrite the old version from Google Drive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- When the file of `blablabla.xlsx` is existing in the specific folder of `FOLDER_ID`, you want to overwrite the file of `blablabla.xlsx`.
- Or, when the file of `blablabla.xlsx` is existing in the specific folder of `FOLDER_ID`, you want to delete the existing file and create it as new file.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

**Before you use this modified script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services)**

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the existing file is overwritten by the blob.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified please modify as follows.

From:

```
if (existing.hasNext()) {
  Browser.msgBox(‘file exists, delete to save the new version after.', Browser.Buttons.OK);

// 'DELETE THE OLD FILE FROM GOOGLE DRIVE' CODE GOES HERE      


  Browser.msgBox(‘file deleted.', Browser.Buttons.OK);
  var arquivo = folder.createFile(blob); //save the new version
  Browser.msgBox(‘new version was saved.', Browser.Buttons.OK);
}
```

To:

```
var arquivo; // Added
if (existing.hasNext()) {
  Browser.msgBox('file exists, delete to save the new version after.', Browser.Buttons.OK);
  Browser.msgBox('file deleted.', Browser.Buttons.OK);
  var id = Drive.Files.update({}, existing.next().getId(), blob).id; // Modified
  arquivo = DriveApp.getFileById(id); // Modified
  Browser.msgBox('new version was saved.', Browser.Buttons.OK);
}
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the existing file is deleted and the blob is created as new file.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified please modify as follows.

From:

```
if (existing.hasNext()) {
  Browser.msgBox(‘file exists, delete to save the new version after.', Browser.Buttons.OK);

// 'DELETE THE OLD FILE FROM GOOGLE DRIVE' CODE GOES HERE      


  Browser.msgBox(‘file deleted.', Browser.Buttons.OK);
  var arquivo = folder.createFile(blob); //save the new version
  Browser.msgBox(‘new version was saved.', Browser.Buttons.OK);
}
```

To:

```
var arquivo; // Added
if (existing.hasNext()) {
  Browser.msgBox('file exists, delete to save the new version after.', Browser.Buttons.OK);
  Browser.msgBox('file deleted.', Browser.Buttons.OK);
  Drive.Files.remove(existing.next().getId()); // Modified
  arquivo = folder.createFile(blob); // Modified
  Browser.msgBox('new version was saved.', Browser.Buttons.OK);
}
```

### Note:

- **At above modified scripts, when the script is run, the existing file is overwritten by the blob and/or deleted. So please be careful this.**
- In your script, `‘` is used as the single quote. In this case, an error occurs. Please modify to `'`. Please be careful this.

### References:

- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/update)
- [Files: delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/delete)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: thanks a lot! i´m not a developer, but i using gscript with google spreadsheet to work with a team e make some things possible! Pattern 1 is better! i was using pattern 2 but some times i have problem with the delay erasing/creating a file with more than 1 person working

Comment: @Roberto Junior Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new issue of `i was using pattern 2 but some times i have problem with the delay erasing/creating a file with more than 1 person working`, although I'm not sure whether I correctly understand about it, how about using Lock Service? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock)? If that didn't resolve your issue, can you post it as new question by including the detail information? By this, it will help users including me think of the solution. At that time, please close this question.

Comment: i think i can´t use this, lock service. The sheet file is colaborative, some people uses at the same time in diferent cells, sheets, but the same file. This routine is being execute all the time, "on edit", exporting the XLSX version of the sheet to be used by other software that uses this file exported

Comment: @Roberto Junior Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About your new issue, from your replying, I cannot understand about the detail situation. Also I cannot see it at your question. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? By this, it will help users think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your new issue soon.

Comment: @Roberto Junior Thank you for replying. But I have to apologize that I cannot resolve your new issue.